# Ubuntu mingw-w64 package referencing non-existent binaries in Windows cross-compile config?

Tags: windows, qt, cross-compiling

So, after installing the `mingw-w64` and `g++-mingw-w64` packages, I'm trying to cross-compile a QT application, running the suggested command:

```
qmake -spec unsupported/win32-g++-cross
```

However, when that runs, I get errors along the lines of:

```
i686-pc-mingw32-g++: Command not found
```

And indeed the `qmake.conf` file in that directory refers to binaries with that prefix `i686-pc-mingw32-g++` does not exist on the system; the mingw applications installed have a `i686-w64-mingw32-` prefix (`i686-w64-mingw32-g++` exists). Clearly, from the name of the manifest, that specification is "unsupported", but I would think it would at least refer to binaries by their proper name that were installed with the same package? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong in general to compile a QT package on Linux, for running on a Windows box after?

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: The QT on the box doing the cross-compile is 4.8.1, `qmake` is version 2.01a.

Comment: That is oooold. Please update it to the latest 4.8.X or even better: 5.3.0.

Comment: Well, it's an Ubuntu Precise (12, LTS) box, which doesn't have Qt5 in its package manager, I think. I've already cross-compiled Qt5 for Windows which is in a parallel folder to the source I'm trying to compile. Should I be using a `qmake` in the cross-compiled libraries?